# What does Load mean in Magento Objects?

Tags: magento

I m trying to learn coding a bit through Magento, and I have to admit that I'm a bit confused about this notion of object chaining in it.

In fact I don't understand when to do a load and when I can avoid it. For exemple:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
```

I would like to get the info of product from a product ID in this case; why do I need to load it?  (`$item` is the loop of all the products of an order)

And here I don't need to do any load:

```
$customer = $payment->getOrder()->getCustomer();
```

I'm sorry in advance for my stupid question: What does load do comparing to my second example? Thanks a lot and have a nice day,

Anselme

Comment: Definitely not a stupid question, Anselme. I will say that you've got guts trying to learn programming from Magento.

Answer (score 4):

Behind the scenes a method like `$payment->getOrder()` is effectively (after checking to see if it's already loaded) doing this:

```
return Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOrderId());
// $this in this context is $payment
```

So a load is still needed to retrieve the relevant data from the database, the `getOrder()` method is just a convenience. The `load()` method itself returns it's class instance, which is why you can assign it to `$product` in your first example. The `getOrder()` and `getCustomer()` methods don't return themselves, they return a different object, which is why `$payment` **is not** assigned to `$customer` in your second example.

The `Mage::getModel()` method is only responsible for determining the correct class and creating a blank instance of it. Instead of a load you could instead set it's data with a `setData()` call, passing a keyed array of values. All of the setters return their object, just like `load()` does.

Comment: I'm only coming back to this because someone else did a late reply to it, but it seems that the person asking the question was wondering why he has to essentially load things twice because it would seem that a collection of items should already have loaded the object he's after. The answer then is because $order->getItems() (for instance) returns a collection of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item models which aren't complete  Mage_Sales_Model_Product models, which explains why he has to do a full load() given the item's product id. You answered the title question but not the extended question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$customer = $payment->getOrder()->getCustomer();
```

It means the id of the customer is already present in the session, so you don't need to explicitly tell magento to load the customer.

In the products case, you have to tell magento the product id of the product you want to get details of.